# Are there better ways to write if statements in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization

So ive been writing Python for a bit now. I've decided to make an app to help my sister with multiplication tables. Im writing the code that will randomly pick from my 10 lists of the diffrent questions (I know there are better ways to write it but it gave me abilities i wanted to use with SQL). lists are by Table (Tone,Ttwo,Tthree, etc.) inside Tone would be ['1*1','1*2',...] then as seen in the if statement it calls by calling the list and problem with randomly generated numbers.

```py
def pick_question():
    Table = random.randint(0,9)
    Col = random.randint(0,9)
    if Table == 0:
        if Col == 0:
            return Tone[0]
        elif Col == 1:
            return Tone[1]
        elif Col == 2:
            return Tone[2]
        elif Col == 3:
            return Tone[3]
        elif Col == 4:
            return Tone[4]
        elif Col == 5:
            return Tone[5]
        elif Col == 6:
            return Tone[6]
        elif Col == 7:
            return Tone[7]
        elif Col == 8:
            return Tone[8]
        elif Col == 9:
            return Tone[9]
    elif Table == 1:
        if Col == 0:
            return Ttwo[0]
        elif Col == 1:
            return Ttwo[1]
        elif Col == 2:
            return Ttwo[2]
        elif Col == 3:
            return Ttwo[3]
        elif Col == 4:
            return Ttwo[4]
        elif Col == 5:
            return Ttwo[5]
        elif Col == 6:
            return Ttwo[6]
        elif Col == 7:
            return Ttwo[7]
        elif Col == 8:
            return Ttwo[8]
        elif Col == 9:
            return Ttwo[9]
```

obviously it would keep going but it was already quite long. was wondering if there was anyway to make this not hae to be so repetitive and look better...

Comment: I'm not a Python developer, but I'd expect that each block could be changed to `return Tone[Col]` or `return Ttwo[Col]` etc, for starters.

Comment: I've updated an answer for you

Answer (score 5):

```py
def pick_question():
    Table = random.randint(0,9)
    Col = random.randint(0,9)
    return [Tone,Ttwo][Table][Col]
```

I guess what you are trying to write is

```
import random

Tone = [f"1*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Ttwo = [f"2*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tthree = [f"3*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tfour = [f"4*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tfive = [f"5*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tsix = [f"6*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tseven = [f"7*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Teight = [f"8*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Tnine = [f"9*{i}" for i in range(1,10)]
Questions = [
    Tone,
    Ttwo,
    Tthree,
    Tfour,
    Tfive,
    Tsix,
    Tseven,
    Teight,
    Tnine,
]

def pick_question():
    Table = random.randint(0,8)
    Col = random.randint(0,8)
    return Questions[Table][Col]

print(pick_question())
```

but I guess what you are trying to do is this:

```py
import random
A=random.randint(1,9)
B=random.randint(1,9)
print(f"{A}*{B}=?")
C=input()
try:
    assert A*B==int(C)
    print("You are RIGHT!")
except:
    print(f"Your are WRONG, right answer is: {A*B}")
```

Good luck with python! it's an amazing language! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a one-dimensional list:

```
def pick_question():
Table = random.randint(0,9)
Col = random.randint(0,9)
if Table == 0:
    return Tone[Col]
elif Table == 1:
    return Ttwo[Col]
```

This will do the trick.
Or even better, a two-dimensional list:

```
def pick_question():
Table = random.randint(0,9)
Col = random.randint(0,9)
List = [Tone, Ttwo]
return List[Table][Col]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write the inner if structures, why not just

```
return Tone[Col]
```

?
In fact, you can create a list with the Tone, Ttwo, etc. inside it and then write

```
return outer_list[Table][Col]
```

```py
def pick_question(list_with_tone_ttwo):
    table = random.randint(0,9)
    col = random.randint(0,9)
    return list_with_tone_ttwo[table][col]
```

EDIT: added full function

Comment: @BryceWellman Can you explain what exactly you ran? Consider printing Table and Col so you can see what they are when you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like this solution with dictionaries and the get method:

```
route = input()
branch = {'y': code1, 'n': code2}.get(route)
```

This shortens your code and will be easier to read.

Comment: You could at least tailor the solution to the example in the question.

Comment: i don't get this code? could you rewrite the variables so i can understand better?

Comment: It uses the get method at the end of the dictionary to choose code to execute by value. If for example route == 'y', then code1 will be executed, or branch will be equal to code1's result or value.